# Problem in animation after exporting

Tags: animation, rigging, export, .fbx, gltf

I have an animation which works perfectly on blender. But when I export it in the form of gltf or fbx there is one spot that doesnt look right.
[image]

This looks right in blender. But after export it looks like this.
[image]

The arm looks really very thin.
This is the file if anyone wants to check it out:
https://we.tl/t-QXCoasPSlJ

Comment: did you rig before or is this your first rig?

Comment: I received a rig from someone. I made animations on top of it. Then converted it into a deformation rig. I have rigged a lot of characters before but have no idea what is causing the problem here